# VBA Excel to Powerpoint, move 1 slide forward

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I am trying to create a macro that opens a pp, and then move forward one slide and make it my active slide.
I feel like there is a simple solution to this but i cant seem to find a code to move me forward one slide.
so far i have

```
Private Sub OpenPowerpoint()
' Opens Presentation.pptx

Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
PPT.Visible = True
PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Test\Template.pptx"

End Sub
```

which open my pp on the first slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there - with your code, just add `PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select`:

```
Private Sub OpenPowerpoint()

    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
    Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application

    PPT.Visible = True
    PPT.Presentations.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Test\Template.pptx"        
    PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Window.View.GoToSlide` will let you go to a specific Slide number.
 
`Window.View.Slide.SlideIndex` will tell you which Slide number you are currently on.
 
`Presentation.Slides.Count` will tell you how many slides there are in a Presentation, so that you don't try to move past the end.
 
Put it together:

```
Private Sub OpenPowerpoint()
    ' Opens Presentation.pptx

    Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application, PPP As PowerPoint.Presentation, PPW As Object
    Set PPT = New PowerPoint.Application
    PPT.Visible = True
    Set PPP = PPT.Presentations.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\Person\Desktop\Test\Template.pptx")
    Set PPW = PPP.Windows(PPP.Windows.Count)
    'If there are more slides, go to the next one
    If PPW.View.Slide.SlideIndex < PPP.Slides.Count Then PPW.View.GotoSlide PPW.View.SlideIndex + 1
End Sub
```